# which jQuery plugin can be used to scroll header?

Tags: jquery, html, css

today i am creating a website for myself and designed tooo, but i am looking for some jquery plugin to use on header, i want to scroll header up and down while user moving page from upwards to downword, facebook header and this website (http://geekz.gr/) is an example for that.

please tell me guys what is this plugin.

thank you all,

regards

Answer (score 3):

In CSS:

```
#your_header { position: fixed; top: 0; }
```

no need to use jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this just with pure CSS

```
#header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the case you need to forcely use jQuery, I can suggest you:

```
$("#header").css({
    "position" : "fixed",
    "top" : 0,
    "left" : 0,
    "width" : "100%";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any jQuery plugin or javascript to achieve a fixed header. All you need is to use the css style `position: fixed`

For the example on geekz.gr, the header is just a div that is 100% wide, has a set height, and then is a fixed position.